# How to insert row for each unique value found in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How could I, in SQL Server 2008, write a SQL statement that would insert one row for each distinct value it finds in one column in the same table?

Edit:
The table I want to add rows to the same table I'm checking.

I have normalized table with a column [Name], and [Hobby], so how do I insert one new hobby for each name?

Input greatly appreciated =]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
INSERT INTO TargetTable (SomeColumn)
SELECT DISTINCT TheSourceColumn From SomeSourceTable;
```

IF that is not what you are looking for please provide more details like what the data model looks like etc.

UPDATE - after edit from OP:

I am not sure that you data model is good but you can do this:

```
INSERT INTO TheTable (NAME, HOBBY)
SELECT DISTINCT X.NAME, @SomeHOBBY FROM TheTable X;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like

```
Insert into table1
Select distinct col1 from tabl2
```

The above should work as long as table1 has just one column of the same data type as col1 of tabl2