# Appending rows for every unique value in column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

**[edit]** [SqlFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=8b76af698f64e67702e8e438da348ac3)

So I have a table, something like this:

```
Food   | Meal      | Amount
Banana | Breakfast | 10 
Banana | Lunch     | 14
Apple  | Breakfast | 40
Apple  | Lunch     | 12
```

and I want to have a **view** that returns a table to concatenates some rows (in this case the two rows with `Carrot` and `Spinach`) per every unique Food/Meal combination.
I.e something like:

```
Food      | Meal       | Amount 
Banana    | Breakfast  | 10
Carrot    | Breakfast  |  5
Spinach   | Breakfast  |  7
Banana    | Lunch      | 14
Carrot    | Lunch      |  5
Spinach   | Lunch      |  7
Apple     | Breakfast  | 40
Carrot    | Breakfast  |  5
Spinach   | Breakfast  |  7
Apple     | Lunch      | 12
Carrot    |   Lunch    | 5
Spinach   | Lunch      | 7
```

etc etc. I have seen examples of how to get this into a table like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239647/how-to-insert-row-for-each-unique-value-found-in-column), but a) that's to insert into a table, and I want to create this in a view, b) I want to "append" multiple rows, not just one.

What would be a good way to go about this?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a **minimal reproducible example**. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: its not clear, please provide a better explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach can be using union all with cte

```
 create table table1(Food   varchar(50), Meal      varchar(50), Amount int);
 insert into table1 values('Banana' , 'Breakfast' , 10);
 insert into table1 values('Banana' , 'Lunch'     , 14);
 insert into table1 values('Apple'  , 'Breakfast' , 40);
 insert into table1 values('Apple'  , 'Lunch'     , 12);
```

Query:

```
 with cte as
 (
   select 'Carrot' food, 5 amount
   union all
   select 'Spinach' food,7 amount
 )
 select * from table1 
 union all
 select food,meal,amount from cte cross join (select  meal from table1)t
```

Output:

| Food | Meal | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Banana | Breakfast | 10 |
| Banana | Lunch | 14 |
| Apple | Breakfast | 40 |
| Apple | Lunch | 12 |
| Carrot | Breakfast | 5 |
| Spinach | Breakfast | 7 |
| Carrot | Lunch | 5 |
| Spinach | Lunch | 7 |
| Carrot | Breakfast | 5 |
| Spinach | Breakfast | 7 |
| Carrot | Lunch | 5 |
| Spinach | Lunch | 7 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=3d643281127f2a64c02ff4baf892fee7)*

To have the output in your desired order:

Query:
with cte as
(
select 'Carrot' food, 5 amount
union all
select 'Spinach' food,7 amount
)
,cte2 as
(
select food,meal,amount,row_number()over(order by (select null))rn from table1
)
,cte3 as
(
select food,meal,amount,rn from cte2
union all
select cte.food,cte2.meal,cte.amount,rn from cte2 cross join  cte
)
select food,meal,amount from cte3 order by rn,food

Output:

| food | meal | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Banana | Breakfast | 10 |
| Carrot | Breakfast | 5 |
| Spinach | Breakfast | 7 |
| Banana | Lunch | 14 |
| Carrot | Lunch | 5 |
| Spinach | Lunch | 7 |
| Apple | Breakfast | 40 |
| Carrot | Breakfast | 5 |
| Spinach | Breakfast | 7 |
| Apple | Lunch | 12 |
| Carrot | Lunch | 5 |
| Spinach | Lunch | 7 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=0f7d00909171807518125b1424bf5d15)*

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, this was a clear example and I was able to understand the logic for my actual use case

Comment: @ocean800 you are most welcome. I have added another version of answer to get you the output in your desired order. Best wishes.

Comment: You can use `VALUES` instead of the CTE